# Vertically Resizable Textareas

Tags: script, style

### Code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange: Vertically Resizable Textareas
// @description Makes Stack Exchange's textareas vertically resizable.
// @version     1.2
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include     http://superuser.com/*
// @include     http://*.superuser.com/*
// @include     http://stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackapps.com/*
// @include     http://askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @include     http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @include     http://*.answers.onstartups.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("textarea{resize:vertical;}"));
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

### About

As part of the CSS reset on January 11, 2012, [resizing textareas was globally disabled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/118644/170332) on all Stack Exchange sites.

While this is definitely a good thing when it comes to horizontal resizing (since it breaks the layout), vertical resizing is useful for tiny textareas (such as the comment area). This user script re-enables it.

#### License

I hereby release this script in the public domain.

#### Platform

This user script has been tested in Google Chrome 16.0.912.7 and Mozilla Firefox 8.0 with Greasemonkey 0.9.13.